# Twitter typeahead.js - grouped results with Hogan template?

Tags: mustache, typeahead.js, hogan.js

I am using (well, would like to use) typeahead.js to search my database by *brand name* and *model name* simultaneously, and display the selectable results grouped by brand name. I thought I could use a simple Mustache template to accomplish this, but I'm not having any luck.

My current typeahead configuration:

```js
myEl.typeahead({
    "name": "models-by-brand",
    "valueKey": "id",
    "remote": "/search/%QUERY",
    "template": '{{#brands}}' +
        '<h4>{{brand_name}}</h4>' +
        '{{#models}}' +
        '<p><a href="#" class="pick-model" data-modelid="{{id}}">{{name}}</a></p>' +
        '{{/models}}' +
        '{{/brands}}',
    "engine": Hogan
});
```

The JSON returned from `/search/super`:

```json
{
    "brands": [
        {
            "brand_name": "Super Widgets",
            "models": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Crazy Widget"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "brand_name": "Acme Widgets",
            "models": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Extra Super Widget"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Double Super Widget"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the typeahead output to be grouped by brand name and selectable by model name thusly:

**Super Widgets**
[Crazy Widget](http://example.com)

**Acme Widgets**
[Extra Super Widget](http://example.com)
[Double Super Widget](http://example.com)

But apparently I can't use Hogan templates with typeahead in this manner (with nested blocks). Typeahead just displays one result with no text.

I tried using a filter function with remote to format each datum, but this only got me a flat list of all the data - I couldn't figure out how to group the results.

Is what I want possible with typeahead templates? Am I just missing something really obvious? I have control over the remote JSON result, so I can change that format if I need to. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible the way you want it.

You could come close by indeed using `filter:`, sorting the result, and creating "dummy" datums for the brand headers. You would have a template that made those headers some non-clickable CSS class. But that would still fall short: the headers would be counted as part of the `limit:` results, for example. And while they may not be clickable, they would still be selectable using the keyboard.

There are 2 workarounds I can think of:

1) If you have a small number of brands, define a dataset for each. That would mean multiple `remote`'s. Each dataset can have its own headers. But again that's only feasible for a small number of brands. If the brands change, the client can get a list of brands and programatically create the datasets.

2) Give up the idea of header per group, and instead have each line in the suggestion drop down be composed of `"{{#brand}} -- {{#model}}"`, and sort those in the `filter:`.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense now I think more about it - the template is meant for per-datum formatting, not formatting for the whole dataset. I can't have multiple remotes as I have a potentially large number of brands. Still, I'm not going to give up yet - maybe I can override typeahead's rendering function or something like that?